# Function definition precedes declaration in namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, forward-declaration

The following bit of code, in which a function definition predeeds its declaration, compiles in VS .NET 2008 and Cygwin gcc 4.8.2. Is it legal?

```
namespace N
{
    int init()      // Definition appears first
    {
        return 42;
    }       
}

namespace N
{
    int init();     // followed by declaration
    const int x = init();
}

int main()
{
}
```

**Edit**

I suppose this isn't too different from the following with also compiles

```
void foo()
{
}

void foo();

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: The second one is not a function definition, it's a declaration. (Otherwise you'd be breaking ODR and it would not compile)

Comment: @Borgleader Typo. Fixed

Comment: @Borgleader Something violating the one definition rule does not imply it will fail to compile.

Comment: Yes it is. Why do you think it might not be?

Comment: @AlanStokes I thought the title of my question made that obvious.

Comment: @MarkB Well... [it does here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de47a0aa38b90c5b) =/

Comment: @Borgleader Yeah, but the diagnostic is not required. Violations of the ODR are ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: @AlanStokes I see what you mean. I've edited the title of my question.

Comment: Your title still doesn't make clear why you would think it's not valid. What rule do you think is being broken? (I've no idea what you mean by "your code sample"; I haven't given one.)

Comment: @AlanStokes Apologies. I meant to say MarkB (deleted the comment). Surely having a definition appear before a declaration is unusual or at least uncommon.

Comment: @MarkB your code sample doesn't quite match mine. I've got just one definition of `N::init()`

Comment: Uncommon does not imply invalid. (See `goto`, `delete`, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[basic.def]/1:

> A declaration (Clause 7) may introduce one or more names into a
>   translation unit **or redeclare names introduced by previous
>   declarations.**

It is fine to (re)declare a name at any time given that the declaration is consistent with respect to earlier ones. In this case, it is consistent, as the type of `init` in both declarations is `int()`. So yes, the code is well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is covered by 3.3.1/4:

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of
> which specifies the same unqualified name,
>
> — they shall all refer to
> the same entity, or all refer to functions and function templates; or

Then 8.3.5/5:

> A single name can be used for several different functions in a single
> scope; this is function overloading (Clause 13). All declarations for
> a function shall agree exactly in both the return type and the
> parameter type- list.

This seems to clearly show that you can declare the same function twice, by having the declarations `...agree exactly in both the return type and the parameter type- list.`